# Git/Stash - No author in changeset

Tags: git, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

We use Atlassian Stash as our code repository. We get the below error very often while archiving the artifacts once the build is complete via Jenkins. The build is a success if I ignore this error. But this error makes the build fail. I could not figure out why / where it is coming from.

I do 'Clean Before Checkout' in the Jenkins Git - Additional Behaviors.

Note:

My Git plugin version is 2.2.5

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a defect. It seems to have been fixed.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16737